Downloading files from Google Drive through Flutter app?
I've been discussing an app I'm building and would like to know whether it is possible to download files from Google Drive directly through a Flutter app for Android and iOS. This needs to be doable by members of the public without logging in to a Google Drive account. Could url_launcher work?
There is no budget for the app, so if it's required to pay for another Google service for this that won't be possible.
I thought of using Google Cloud storage but this requires some payment. I tried simply adding a Google Drive link to the standard url_launcher function and got the message "Could not find any Google accounts, exiting application" in the emulator.

To meet your requirements, you can use url_launcher to download files from Google Drive by creating a public link. The link should be accessible without logging into a Google Drive account, but the device will need to have a Google account added. Most users already have a Google account on their device, especially if they use the Play Store.
